# Why does increasing the coils on the iron nail can stronger the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

When I increase the number of coils of wire, the strength of an electromagnet is stronger. Can you explain it using easy scientific words? I'm explaining this to my kids. Thanks! :D

Comment: the strength of the magnetic field is directly proportional to the current flow, so if you double the number of coils the magnetic field strength doubles (this is ampere law) :D

Comment: @user6760, doubling the number of coils doesn't double the current $I$ through the coil but, as written, your comment implies this.  Doubling the number of coils doubles the mmf [(ampere-turns)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-turn):  *"By maintaining the same current and increasing the number of loops or turns of the coil, the strength of the magnetic field increases because each loop or turn of the coil sets up its own magnetic field. The magnetic field unites with the fields of the other loops to produce the field around the entire coil making the total magnetic field stronger."*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: I stands corrected, strength of magnetic field for coil is equal to (current x number of coils)/length so that's why I said that which is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Current - moving electrons - makes a magnetic field. If you have a long straight wire with a current flowing in it, the entire wire has a magnetic field around it. If you put a nail near the wire, the magnetic field will exert a force on the nail.

The force is stronger if the nail is near the wire. A nail can only be near a small section of a long straight wire.

One way to make the force stronger is to put more wire next to the nail. Wrapping the wire into a coil does this. The more coils you have, the more wire is near the nail.

This glosses over a few things. For example, direction is important. The coils all have to run the same way. This explanation just gives a feel for the idea. If you want more detail, it gets mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you explain it using easy scientific words? I'm explaining this to my kids.

In metals are tiny particles, called electrons, and we are able to make them flowing through wires.

If you make a coil from a wire and connect the ends of the wire to the poles of a battery the flowing electrons in the coil produce a magnetic field.

Even one turn of the wire makes a magnetic field and for each winding of the wire the magnetic field gets stronger.

For you: There is a saturation of this field and adding more and more windings does not increase the strength of the field to infinity.